# How do two species from the same buffer system have different pKa values?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, ph, buffer

> $$
> \begin{array}{lr}
> \hline
> \text{Reagent}~(\pu{0.1 M}~\text{solutions}) & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} \\
> \hline
> \text{Ammonia} & 9.25 \\
> \text{Acetic acid} & 4.75 \\
> \text{Ammonium chloride} & 9.24 \\
> \text{Sodium acetate} & 4.75 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> Using the equation below, calculate the ratio of $[\text{base}]$ to $[\text{acid}]$ to get the buffer of desired $\mathrm{pH}.$
>
> $$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\frac{[\text{base}]}{[\text{acid}]}$$

I am tasked to create a buffer solution with a $\mathrm{pH}$ level of $9.02.$ Given a table filled with the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of two different buffer systems, I'm not sure if I should either use the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of ammonia or the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of ammonium chloride for the calculation.

Why do ammonia and ammonium chloride have different $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values despite being from the same buffer system?

Comment: 9.24 is no different from 9.25.

Comment: The table is misleading. Ammonia itself as an acid would produce $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{NH2-}$, with a very very low Ka. Ammonia actually acts as a base. The value quoted in the table is the pKa of ammonia's conjugate acid, ammonium ion

Comment: I actually had the same thought on why Ammonia had a pKa when it acts as a base. Anyways, thank you so much for everyone's help!

Comment: If ammonia bothers you, so should sodium acetate, as it is the same case. Both refer to pKa of their conjugate(d?) acid.( ammonium and acetic acid )

Comment: Yup, also Sodium Acetate, but for this problem, I didn't bother minding Acetic Acid and Sodium Acetate since it wouldn't help me in solving the problem.

Comment: In fact, it could help, as you could more easily see, why ammonia and ammonium chloride refer to ( practically ) the same value - the acidity constant of ammonium. The tiny difference is due different data source.

Comment: Even though both are practically the same value (9.24 & 9.25), would you consider one value to be "more" correct than the other? or are they both just as correct as one another?

Comment: Can a constant (for the same conditions) have 2 different, equally correct values ? (rhetorical question ). The answer to quour question is matter of short research, which I would let on you. It is on an edge on a rounding error. Another question is the true value versus equally confident different values, due statistical errors.

Comment: I see. It's more of a statistical thing rather than a chemistry thing. I'll look into it for more information. Thanks!